# Passing second value in Ajax data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an array and I am passing it to PHP via AJAX fine - getting correct response from PHP file. However, I am now looking to include an "id" in the AJAX's data object to send along to PHP file with the original array. I cannot seem to figure that out. If anyone has any input, I greatly appreciate it.

```
var id = $("input[name='id']").val();
var posArr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'php/file.php',
  data: { positions: posArr },
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(output) {
    console.log('success -> ' + output);
  },
  error: function(output) {
    console.log('fail -> ' + output);
  }
});
```

My goal is to use the id passed along to search the database according to that id, and then store/update the table with the items in the array (posArr).

Thank you.

Comment: `data: { positions: posArr, id : id },` Easy peezy lemon squeezy.

Comment: How could I check the appropriate response from PHP back to ajax? I have: $id = $_POST['id'];  $orderArr = $_POST['positions']; echo json_encode($orderArr);  echo $id;

Comment: Watch the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I see it. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am now looking to include an "id" in the AJAX's data object

Then just include it in the object that's being sent to the server:

```
data: { positions: posArr, id: id }
```

Server-side it would be read just like the `positions` data element.  In this case simply:

```
$_POST['id']
```

Comment: How would I echo the response back to AJAX? I have:  $id = $_POST['id'];
$orderArr = $_POST['positions'];  echo json_encode($orderArr);  echo $id; But I get error.

Comment: @Sergio: It's not really clear to me why you need to respond to the client with the same exact values the client just sent you, but in general you would create an object and echo the JSON of that object.  Currently echoing one and then the other results in the full response being malformed JSON.  So you create an object which holds *both* the array and the id, and `json_encode()` *that* object.  An associative array might even do the trick.  For example: `echo json_encode(array('positions' => $orderArr, 'id' => $id));`

Comment: Just for testing purposes really. Just so I know I'm getting what I am expecting.

Comment: I'm failing to understand and getting the results using the echo example above. I am getting a success message but the output is [object Object]. Can you explain why it needs to be converted back into an array containing those objects?

Comment: @Sergio: JavaScript doesn't have any way to know what to display for an object, only for basic types. So outputting the entire object would result in `[object Object]`. You'd have to output specifically what you want from that object, such as individual properties. If it's just for debugging, you can pass the object to `console.log()` which would output the whole object to the browser's debugging console. As for why you need to create an object, it's because the JSON response needs to be *one* entity in order to be parsed. So multiple response values would be properties on a containing object.

Comment: Ahh got it. So simply doing object.id and object.positions in the console log would display the results. It's working. Perfect. Thank you.